# how to manage UIViewControllers which open and reopen each other

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 UIViewControllers which open each others, and my problem begins when it happens several times, so when the user tap the close button, there are so many instance of those viewcontrollers,

I'm not using Segue and use this code below

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "verifySMSView") as! SMSVerificationViewController
            vc.delegate = self
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is the Gif file which shows my problem ( [LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4g0fzv282jru4q8/pro.gif) )

how to manage viewcotrollers and stop reopen again, 
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly you want to achieve? And how you dismiss controllers at the moment?

Comment: please check the LINK(which I have put in my question) you will find out my problem.Imagine I have A and B viewcontorller, A has a button which makes B, and B has a button which makes A, when we do it several times, so we have number of A and number of B, but I wanna have only one instance!

Comment: Do you really want B to make A again? Or do you just want to dismiss B and get back to A?

Comment: I wanna, both make each other, but once!

Answer (score 0):

Write This Code

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

On Click event of "I have already account" button

Comment: I already did this, but it didn't work because and gets me the error of "View Hierarchy"

Comment: here you are : <SignInViewController: 0x7fd18c8a0a00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple demo app (no storyboard, just code) and everything works as expected. Compare the following to your code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.rootViewController = ViewControllerA()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }

}

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    let createNewAccountButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button.setTitle("Create new account", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let viewControllerB = ViewControllerB()
        present(viewControllerB, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        view.addSubview(createNewAccountButton)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            createNewAccountButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            createNewAccountButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        ])
    }
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    let alreadyHaveAnAccountButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button.setTitle("I already have an account", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .darkGray

        view.addSubview(alreadyHaveAnAccountButton)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            alreadyHaveAnAccountButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            alreadyHaveAnAccountButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Andre, but this code is not the thing I want! :)